# 3 Divs, One container, Responsive

Tags: html, css, contains

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LTchE/10/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="x"></div>
        <div class="y"></div>
        <div class="z"></div>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #de291e;
}
.x {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x505') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 300px;
    width:100%;
    height: 505px;

    display: block;
    float:left;
}
    .y {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/500x505') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 500px;
    width:100%;
    height: 505px;

    display: block;
    float:left;
}
    .z {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/100x505') no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 505px;
    width:100%;

    display: block;
    float:left;
}
```

i have this 3 divs in the screen, but when resizing the windows, they break into new rows...

i want then to continue in the same row, like being responsive..

anyone can help? im searching this for hours now.. :(

(also is it possible to they always match the screen size? ) for now the max value is 900px.. but I dont know, maybe if some one has a huge screen, to fit it)

Comment: You can put a picture of how you want the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work in percentages.

Your wrapper is 100% and you have 3 divs side by side inside that wrapper.
Those 3 divs need to equal 100% so the first div can be 40%, the second 50% and the last 10% (Just play around until you get what you like)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.x {
    background-color:green;
    width:40%;
    height: 505px;
    float:left;
}
    .y {
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
    height: 505px;
    float:left;
}
    .z {
    background-color:red;
    height: 505px;
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: solved <3 thanksss i had to use like 27.23% insane percents to align, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is Width in your div's css, what your code says is that take the full with that is given to parent that might be suppose `1000px` with `width:100%` but on the other hand you set a limit of `max-width:300px` so it wants to take the full width i.e. `1000px` on the screen but `max-width` limits it to `300px` so it looks like everything is working fine but there is a conflict in your css which is not noticable and then you just resize your window div moves to next row because there is not enough space. Basically what you have to do is give it a width that is actually need.

like i gave a value of `width:33%` to all the 3 divs rather than giving all of them `100%` individually and code worked fine.